# Passar parâmetros fora do jQuery.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Boa noite, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de determinar os parâmetros fora da função + - dessa maneira?

Tipo, estou dizendo que na var `sintax` os parâmetros da função `ajax` antes de rodar quando `re == 1` ou não.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('form._returnJson').submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
        var re    = $(this).attr("changeBut");

        if($re == 1)
            var sintax = {
                type: "POST",
                url: _url+"/config/server.php",
                data: dados,
                dataType: 'json', // obj.return obj.token obj.mensagem
                cache: false,
            }
        } else {
            var formulario = document.getElementById(this);
            var dados = new FormData(formulario);

            var sintax = {
                type: "POST",
                url: _url+"/config/server.php",
                data: dados,
                dataType: 'json', // obj.return obj.token obj.mensagem
                cache: false,
                processData: false,  
                contentType: false,
            }
        }

        jQuery.ajax({
            sintax,
            sucess: function(){},
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Estou precisando determinar dois tipo de ajax, um para upload de imagem e outro de dados, mas queria fazer isso sem precisar criar dois ajax, em uma unica entendem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível, mas da forma que você está fazendo, todas as propriedades vão ficar dentro do objeto `sintax`, ou seja, seu código será interpretado dessa forma:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    sintax: {
        type: "POST",
        url: _url+"/config/server.php",
        data: dados,
        dataType: 'json', // obj.return obj.token obj.mensagem
        cache: false
    },
    sucess: function(){},
});
```

Para passar apenas as propriedades de `sintax`, e não o objeto inteiro, use o operador `...` para desestruturar seu objeto, dessa maneira:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...sintax,
     sucess: function(){},
});
```

Assim o código será interpretado da seguinte maneira:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: _url+"/config/server.php",
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json', // obj.return obj.token obj.mensagem
    cache: false,
    sucess: function(){},
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado. ;)